# Can't reload self-made captcha on the page using JS

Tags: javascript, captcha

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById("capchaimage").src="captcha.php"><img id="captchaimage" src="http://website.org/captcha.php" border="0" width="70" height="20" alt="Captcha image"></a>
```

Captcha image successfully loads but it's not possible to reload it with the code above. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your images are cached. Add a random string `+(new Date).getTime()` to at the query string after the image URL:

```
document.getElementById("capchaimage").src="captcha.php?"+ (new Date).getTime();
```

Comment: `<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById("captchaimage").src="captcha.php?"+ (new Date).getTime();"><img id="captchaimage" src="http://5ch.su/captcha.php" border="0" width="70" height="20" alt="Captcha image"></a>` Still doesn't work

Comment: Replace the inner quotes by`&quot;` or `'` (single-quotation mark).

Comment: Thanks for priceless help, Rob! I owe you :)

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing image src with exactly the same string.

You can try to work around that by using some "fake" arguments:

```
http://website.org/captcha.php?fake=234342412341
```

That way the browser will be forced to reload. The argument needs to be different each time of course (random, or just counter)

Answer (score 0):

Look carefully at your code:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="document.getElementById("capchaimage").src="captcha.php"><img id="captchaimage" src="http://website.org/captcha.php" border="0" width="70" height="20" alt="Captcha image"></a>
                                      ^                        ^
```

I'm surprised you are not getting JavaScript syntax errors. My advise is to move code to external functions to avoid the need of complex escaping.